# LINQ - Select Over Dynamic - Implicit Conversion Error - Unexpected Type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have this piece of code:

```
public IEnumerable<IViewModel> MapRowsToModels(Type viewType, IEnumerable<dynamic> rows)
{
    return rows.Select(row =>
    {
        var a = MapRowToModel(viewType, row);  // a is of type dynamic, why!!!?
        return a;
    });
}

public abstract IViewModel MapRowToModel(Type viewType, dynamic row);
```

So there we have a list of dynamics that I iterate over and then transform to another type with `Select`, that I have an implementation for. My question is strictly about the line:

```
var a = MapRowToModel(viewType, row); // a is of type dynamic, why?
```

This won't compile, and I hover over a, it shows a is of type dynamic. Why? My method returns a type of IViewModel, why is the type dynamic?

Comment: dynamic contaminates all.

Comment: @jn1kk if you don't mind, can you accept the answer you ended up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic),

> The result of most dynamic operations is itself `dynamic`.

In order to cast `dynamic` to another type you should use either implicit or explicit cast, e.g.:

```
IViewModel a = MapRowToModel(viewType, row);
```

or

```
var a = (IViewModel)MapRowToModel(viewType, row);
```

Comment: If I call this method in a non-linq function, the result doesn't need a cast.

Comment: @jn1kk there must be a cast somewhere else, for example, when returning from a function... Could you provide the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you are looking for by making `MapRowsToModels` a generic function.

With no constraints on `T`, it will act similar to what you expected out of the `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and you will get the dynamic behavior you want from `MapRowToModel`

```
public IEnumerable<IViewModel> MapRowsToModels<T>(Type viewType, IEnumerable<T> rows)
{
    return rows.Select(row =>
    {
        var a = MapRowToModel(viewType, row);
        return a;
    });
}

public abstract IViewModel MapRowToModel(Type viewType, dynamic row);
```